# While-loop equals to not working properly (java bank account)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

So my task is to write a bank-account program that asks wether you want to deposit or withdraw money, it asks for how much and at last if I want to continue or not, and if not it will show my current account balance. Example:

Deposit or withdraw (0-deposit, 1-withdraw):
How much?
Do you want to continue?

Balance: XX.XX

The program should be looped and break when the answer is "Y" on "Do you want to quit?".

```
package Account;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class bankVisit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        bankAccount account = new bankAccount();

        String respond = "N";

        System.out.print("Deposit or withdraw (0-deposit, 1-withdraw): ");
        int choice = scan.nextInt();

        while (respond.equals("N")) {
            if (choice == 0) {
                System.out.print("Amount: ");
                double total = scan.nextDouble();
                account.credit(total);

                System.out.print("Do you want to quit? ");
                respond = scan.next();
            } else if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.print("Amount: ");
                double total = scan.nextDouble();
                account.withdraw(total);

                System.out.print("Do you want to quit? ");
                respond = scan.next();
            }

            System.out.print("Deposit or withdraw (0-deposit, 1-withdraw): ");
            choice = scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Balance: " + account.getBalance());

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

I get it to loop, but I dont get how I should make the loop to quit, and post my balance, it keeps looping even though "respond" not equals "N".. Any ideas? Im very new to Java so anything will do.

Comment: add scan.nextline(); right after scan.nextDouble();, just to see if it will help.

Comment: You're always going to ask "Deposit or withdraw" again, even after you've asked "Quit?" and gotten that answer.  If you didn't answer "N" to the 'Quit" prompt, the loop should end after you answer the extraneous "Deposit or withdraw" prompt.